# Highlight link with click

Tags: html, jquery-ui

I'd like to create a link that when it is clicked it will open up a some sort of dialog with some text a user can copy.

I was going to use jquery ui dialog for this but I'm wondering if there is something else I should consider?

Ideally I'd like to have that text highlighted so it is ready to copy.  Don't think I can do this with jquery dialog?

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: You could put a `textarea` within the dialog and select the text ready for copy / paste

Comment: Using highlightTextarea method? That just highlights but it is not for copy/paste AFAIK.  Or did you mean something else?

Comment: Just added an answer with an example ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

HTML :

```
<div id="dialog">
   <textarea id="textbox">some text to copy and paste</textarea>
</div>​
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#dialog').dialog();
$('#textbox').focus().select();​
```

This opens a dialog and then selects all of the text within the textarea. Because the `focus` function is used you can Ctrl+C straight off as the text is already in focus and selected.

Working demo : http://jsfiddle.net/eZbXD/

Comment: Thanks, I'm struggling with changing the html to a link but I'm sure I'll figure it out...

Answer (score 1):

Instead of opening a dialog, you can show a textbox in which the link is selected and ready to copy. I have done something like that before. Look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6U48e/4/). You can remove unnecessary codes and give some style according to your need.